# Fingerprint orientation map in java

Tags: java, image-processing, orientation, fingerprint

I have implemented the code for ridge orientation in java.I have make the 16*16 block and got the orientation angle for each block.

Code I have implemented to get the orientation angle :

```
public static double angle(int i,int j,int[][] pixel){
    double angle = 0;
    double num = 0;
    double denom =0;
    for(int x=i;x<i+16;x++){
        for(int y=j;y<j+16;y++){
            try {
                int gx = sobelOperatorX(i, j, pixel);
                int gy = sobelOperatorY(i, j, pixel);
                num += (2 * gx * gy);
                denom +=((gx * gx) - (gy * gy));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    }
    angle = 0.5 * Math.atan(num/denom);
    return angle;
}

public static int sobelOperatorX(int x,int y,int[][] pixel){
    int k=2;
    int Gx=0;
    Gx = (((pixel[x+1][y-1]+k*pixel[x+1][y]+pixel[x+1][y+1])-(pixel[x-1][y-1]+k*pixel[x-1][y]+pixel[x-1][y+1]))/(k+2));
    return Gx;
}

public static int sobelOperatorY(int x,int y,int[][] pixel){
    int k=2;
    int Gy=0;
    Gy = (((pixel[x-1][y-1]+k*pixel[x][y-1]+pixel[x+1][y-1])-(pixel[x-1][y+1]+k*pixel[x][y+1]+pixel[x+1][y+1]))/(k+2));
    return Gy;
}
```

Now I am trying to get [orientation map](http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/en-us/book/understanding-biometrics/types/feature-extraction/orientation) for the fingerprint image.The output image should be like this :

[image]

Is there any algorithm to find out direction of a ridge or to get orientation map for the fingerprint image ?

Comment: What do you mean by "orientation map"? Can you give some kind of definition?

Comment: The orientation is an angle formed by the ridge inclination and the horizontal line. Here is the supporting link http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/en-us/book/understanding-biometrics/types/feature-extraction/orientation

Comment: @lnwvr I have added a link in my question.Please refer it.